# Runtime ClassNotFoundException during jar execution on Yarn cluster mode

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, hadoop, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to run a java application on a Hadoop/Cloudera cluster.

I am running the application jar on a hadoop cloudera custer with the following command:

```
spark-submit --master yarn TmcStreamingProcessor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 2g --jars TmcStreamingProcessor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

It should read from a Kafka streaming as a comsumer, while another java application acts as producer. Once it reads the streaming data, the application should write on mongoDB using Spark Structured-Streaming as follows:

```
        // write on MongoDB
        StreamingQuery streamingQuery = rowDatasetCounted
                .repartition(1)
                .selectExpr("... several columns ...")
                .writeStream()
//                .format("console")
//                .outputMode("complete")
                .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointFolder)
                .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(Duration.apply(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .foreach(forEachWriterMongo)
                .start();
```

The snippet is taken from the TmcStreamingMongo class,
sadly, after a few seconds of execution, i get a warning with the following exception:

```
WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 
(TID 54, hadoop03.vmware.local, executor 4): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 

TmcStreamingProcessor.utility.ForEachWriterMongo

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1868)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1408)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Following this warning, the job execution stops with an error having the same body of the previously reported warning. I tried many solutions but i cannot find the cause for this odd behavior, since the missing class is obviously there, even weirder, the error keep showing even when i remove all body in the ForEachWriterMongo Class.

**TmcStreamingMongo :**

```
import TmcStreamingProcessor.model.TmcPathRawTimestamp;
import TmcStreamingProcessor.utility.ForEachWriterMongo;
import TmcStreamingProcessor.utility.KafkaConfig;
import TmcStreamingProcessor.utility.SparkSessionBean;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class TmcStreamingMongo implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("singletonSparkSession")
    private SparkSessionBean sparkSessionBean;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaConfig kafkaConfig;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.grouped}")
    private String topic;

    @Autowired
    ForEachWriterMongo forEachWriterMongo;

    @Value("${checkpointMongo.base.path}")
    private String checkpointFolder;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public void start() {
//        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SparkSession spark = sparkSessionBean.getSpark();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", (String) kafkaConfig.getKafkaConfig().get("bootstrap.servers"))
                .option("subscribe", topic)
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
                .load();

//        Dataset<TmcPathRawTimestamp> tmcPathRawDataset = df.map((MapFunction<Row, TmcPathRawTimestamp>) msg -> {
//            TmcPathRaw tmcPathRawMapped = objectMapper.readValue((byte[]) msg.get(1), TmcPathRaw.class);
//
//            return new TmcPathRawTimestamp(
//                    tmcPathRawMapped, new Timestamp(tmcPathRawMapped.getAvgGpsTime().getTime()));
//        }, Encoders.bean(TmcPathRawTimestamp.class));

//
        StructType tmcStruct = new StructType()
                 "...
                   several columns
                 ..."

        df.printSchema();

        Dataset<Row> tmcPathRawDatasetTemp = df
                .select(from_json(col("value").cast(DataTypes.StringType), tmcStruct).as("json"));

        tmcPathRawDatasetTemp.printSchema();

        Dataset<TmcPathRawTimestamp> tmcPathRawDataset = tmcPathRawDatasetTemp
                .selectExpr("...
                            several columns
                 ...")
                .as(Encoders.bean(TmcPathRawTimestamp.class));

        RelationalGroupedDataset groupedTmcPathRawDataset = tmcPathRawDataset
                .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 seconds")
                .groupBy(
                        functions.window(functions.col("timestamp"), "1 minute"),
                        functions.col("...several columns..."),
                     
                );

        Dataset<Row> rowDatasetCounted = groupedTmcPathRawDataset.agg("...aggregation processing...");

        // write on MongoDB
        StreamingQuery streamingQuery = rowDatasetCounted
                .repartition(1)
                .selectExpr("... several columns ...")
                .writeStream()
//                .format("console")
//                .outputMode("complete")
                .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointFolder)
                .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(Duration.apply(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .foreach(forEachWriterMongo)
                .start();

        streamingQuery.awaitTermination();
    }
```

**ForEachWriterMongoClass:**

```
import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.netcomgroup.eu.TmcStreamingProcessor.model.TmcPathGrouped;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class ForEachWriterMongo extends ForeachWriter<Row> implements Serializable {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String dbName;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.collection}")
    private String dbCollection;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String dbHost;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    private int dbPort;

    private MongoClient mongoClient;

    private List<TmcPathGrouped> tmcPathGroupedList;

    @Override
    public boolean open(long l, long l1) {
        ForEachWriterMongo.log.info("Open inserting data on MongoDB...");
        mongoClient = this.getMongoClient();
        tmcPathGroupedList = new ArrayList<>();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Row r) {
        TmcPathGrouped tmcPathGrouped =
                new TmcPathGrouped(
                        r.getInt(0), r.getInt(1), r.getInt(2), r.getInt(3), r.getLong(4),
                        r.getDouble(5), r.getTimestamp(6), r.getTimestamp(7),
                        r.getTimestamp(8), r.getTimestamp(9)
                );

        tmcPathGroupedList.add(tmcPathGrouped);
    }

    @Override
    public void close(Throwable throwable) {
        if(!tmcPathGroupedList.isEmpty()){
            this.write();
        }

        tmcPathGroupedList.clear();
        mongoClient.close();
    }

    @Transactional("mongoDbTransactionManager")
    public void write() {
        ForEachWriterMongo.log.info("Start insert on Mongo...");
        mongoClient.getDatabase(this.dbName).getCollection(this.dbCollection).insertMany(tmcPathGroupedList);
        ForEachWriterMongo.log.info("Finished insert on Mongo...");
    }

    public MongoClient getMongoClient() {
        final ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://" + this.dbHost + ":" +
                this.dbPort + "/" + dbName);
        final MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .writeConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY)
                .readConcern(ReadConcern.MAJORITY)
                .readPreference(ReadPreference.primary())
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();

        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }

}
```

**Backgroud information:**

Detailed components with versions:

```
{
    "name": "hadoop",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "3.0.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "3.0.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "parquet",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "1.9.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "1.9.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "kafka",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "2.2.1+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "2.2.1-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "solr",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "7.4.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "7.4.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "pig",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "0.17.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "0.17.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "kite",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "1.0.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "1.0.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "sqoop",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "1.4.7+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "1.4.7-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "hive",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "2.1.1+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "2.1.1-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "sentry",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "2.1.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "2.1.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "hbase-solr",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "1.5+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "1.5-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "flume-ng",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "1.9.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "1.9.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "hive-hcatalog",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "2.1.1+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "2.1.1-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "hadoop-httpfs",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "3.0.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "3.0.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "kudu",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "1.10.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "1.10.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "oozie",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "5.1.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "5.1.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "hadoop-kms",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "3.0.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "3.0.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "zookeeper",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "3.4.5+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "3.4.5-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "hadoop-hdfs",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "3.0.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "3.0.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "hadoop-yarn",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "3.0.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "3.0.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "spark",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "2.4.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "2.4.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "hadoop-mapreduce",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "3.0.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "3.0.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "hbase",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "2.1.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "2.1.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "hue",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "4.2.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "4.2.0-cdh6.3.2"
},

{
    "name": "impala",
    "pkg_release": "1605554",
    "pkg_version": "3.2.0+cdh6.3.2",
    "version": "3.2.0-cdh6.3.2"
```

**Previously attempted solutions:**
I tried several configurations to build my SparkSession (most of them now are left there as a comment to remind me that i have already attempted that solution). Sadly, no config solved my problem.

```
// .master("yarn")
// .master("spark://192.168.102.24:7077")
.master("local[*]")
        .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 50)
// .config("spark.jars", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/TmcStreamingProcessor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")
// .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://192.168.102.24:8020/user/spark-warehouse")
// .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath","hdfs://192.168.102.24:8020/user/yarn-jars/*")
// .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "hdfs://192.168.102.24:8020/user/yarn-jars/*")
        .config("spark.driver.userClassPathFirst", false)
// .config("spark.driver.extraLibraryPath", "hdfs://192.168.102.24:8020/user/yarn-jars/*")
// .enableHiveSupport()
//.config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory")
        .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled",false)
        .getOrCreate();
```

I have tried several solutions found on similar question, like:

-Uploading the jar manually on each cluster node.

-Uploading the jar in the hdfs shared folder.

-Specifying jar location using the --jars option on spark submit (or, code-side, in the sparkSession config).

-Uploading all project dependency on hdfs shared folder, specifying hdfs-driver-classpath and hdfs-executor-classpath on cluster configuration.

But none of this solutions worked for me.

Thank you in advice for an answer!